# Binding WPF Image control events with MVVM Light EventToCommand

Tags: wpf, image, binding, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

I want to wire command to Image's MouseDown event in WPF MVVMLight applcation. I have following code :

```
<Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Image Margin="3" Name="Content" Source="{Binding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand 
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectMediaCommand}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>    
                </Image>
            </Border>
```

When i paste < Triggers > piece into other control (say textblock in same view), MouseDown does occur (bindings are correct). Tried even put it inside Border, still no effect. I guess i'm missing something. Any ideas what? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your Output window for binding errors, probably the FindAncestor doesn't work .. ?

Comment: No, bindings are correct, substituted Image with Button and everything worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the interaction.triggers section is right. so the error is just in your command binding. like SvenG suggested check your vs output window or use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to look for binding errors.

my working example:

```
    <Image Source="arrange.png" Grid.Row="1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand 
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.OpenCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Image>
```

this means your usercontrol need a datacontext/viewmodel with a ICommand property OpenCommand.

Comment: Nice tool. Will try to use it.